# SQL filter only if each unique value has more than N records

Tags: hive

Here is my sample SQL statement:

```
SELECT DAY,
       name,
       value
FROM my_table
WHERE DAY = '${date}'
GROUP BY DAY
         name,
         value
ORDER BY name ASC
```

For example, 3 unique names in 'name' column: Alice, Bob, Clark.

Alice has 5 rows, Bob has 9 rows, Clark has 12 rows.

I want to add a filter if rows with same value > 10 rows. 'Clark' satisfies in this case.

How to add this? under WHERE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Welcome**.

Here is what you want. But please follow the notes given below too.

```
SELECT day,
       ip_address,
       user_name,
       timestamp,
       count(ip_address) AS tct
FROM my_table
WHERE day = current_date()
GROUP BY ip_address
HAVING tct> 10
ORDER BY ip_address ASC
```

1. Do not use select * instead give specific column names.
2. You are speaking of count per name in your question but your code groups by DAY, name, value - check if it is fine for you.
3. It is better (always) to list your data structure and the output needed along with your code to get best answer.

Comment: If this works, please mark it as correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I modify the question. I want to select all the columns. do i need to modifty group by? I got 0 results

Comment: I suspected your GROUP BY.  Give all column names you want at SELECT. But GROUP BY the exact column (or columns) with which you need to get totals. Also, add **count(name) as tct** and **HAVING tct>10** in your code as mentioned in my original answer.

Comment: if i do not list all columns in Group By, hive will give me error "Expression not in GROUP BY key 'xxx' "

Comment: Please post your complete (current) code.

Comment: i post in your answer part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104685/discussion-between-natarajan-n-napoleon-and-tjclk).

Comment: Removing the ORDER BY clause might help removing the Error 10025.

Comment: still cannot solve

Comment: This should work except the mentioned two. 1. Check your environment where the group by logic changes in strict mode. 2. for hive, ORDER BY generates the same error 10025 (you shall search for the same).

Comment: i find answer here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260125/hive-sql-error-10025-expression-not-in-group-by-key